# Can I set global defaults of QoS 2 and ToS 16 to apply, e.g., to gSOAP service?

Tags: sockets, gsoap, qos

The source code for soapcpp2.cpp contains a number of calls to setsockopt(), but none for IP_TOS or SO_PRIORITY.  If possibly, I would like to be able to have these default to 16 and 2, respectively, to make services subservient to messaging.  Is there a way to do this in Linux (Ubuntu and/or CentOS)?  Requiring sudo is not an issue.  Thx

Comment: An interesting aside I discovered is that unless one sets TOS first, it will override the QOS value with a default based on the type.

Comment: Another thought: If the server interface intercepts soap->socket and sets TOS and QOS on that, will that determine the level at which the XML response is communicated to the client?  Does the fact that the response is TCP complicate matters?